# Global dark theme not working with Ambiance in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gnome-tweak-tool

I cannot get the global dark theme with Ambiance and any other themes in Ubuntu 17.10 via the gnome-tweak-tool. The file settings.ini has correct settings:

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

I login using Xorg although the problem is the same on wailand.